# Here maps and restrictions to specific domains

Tags: javascript, security, here-api

I subscribed to a free plan to Here Maps.

I created an application, i have got an app_code and an app_id.

I tried to restrict theses credentials by domain :

- my-app.my-internal-domain.com (that use the javascript api)
- xxxxxx.cloudfront.net (that generate tiles and cache them)

If i try to configure wrong domains on Here maps :

- I can see a 401 error when i try to generate tile, so, it's works.
- But i always can navigate on the map, I shouldn't, right ?

What is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

The tiles are cached on the client side as well. Could you try clearing your browser cache and check if still map is shown ? Are you able to see the request being sent behind the scenes using the developer tools, are they being served from server or client cache ?